# Is a StateObject more performant when instantiated in a View instead of the top-level App?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've observed performance differences based on the location of my instantiated `StateObject`. Specifically, I noticed that when my top-level `View` owns the `StateObject`, my app's usage on the main thread decreases by ~5%. For some reason, instantiating this `StateObject` in a SwiftUI `App` is less performant. My expectation is that performance would be identical since nothing else changed.

While that 5% might not seem like much, the result might be 10-15% higher CPU utilization on some devices. It's worth nothing that in my `StateObject`, I've defined a `CADisplayLink` which runs a callback on every frame, so this is where most of the compute gets used.

For some reason, this:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var someStateObject = SomeStateObject()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Is more performant than this:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var someStateObject = SomeStateObject()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Is there something about SwiftUI's `App` that would create these performance differences?

Comment: So why are you trying to use `CADisplayLink` in SwiftUI state? That seems like a performance problem in itself.

Comment: @malhal my CADisplayLink doesn't necessarily need to be in a StateObject, what would be a better alternative for a SwiftUI app?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the issue had to do with CADisplayLink getting called from the App level, rather than the View. The perf issue was fixed once I moved my CADisplayLink to the view.